# Split Binomial Heap

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to think of an idea to make a new Split operation that By given a [Binomial heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap).

The question is how to split binomial heap (size n) into binomial heap
of size k (k < n),  and binomial heap of size n-k within the minimal time of running.

Comment: What would the benefit of having this split operation be (there's a reason why heaps are split 50/50)? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `kth` largest element of a set in `O(n)` time with the median of medians algorithm. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm).

When you have that value, you can read all values from the original heap (don't need to extract, their order doesn't matter on read, only on write in the new arrays. This has the added benefit of not messing with the original heap. Yay.) and put into the large or small heap, depending on their relation to the `kth` value. Each extraction is `O(1)` and occurs `n` times. Each insert is `O(lg n)` and occurs `n` times.

```
Total running time: n +  n  + n lg n = O(n lg n)
                    |    |       |
             selection   |    inserts
                     extraction
```

Comment: if you're already performing O(nlogn) operations, why not just get all values from the original heap sorted, find the kth number, insert all number bigger than that into a heap, and all smaller than that into another heap? seems simpler than using median algorithm...

Comment: @Gal because there isn't a need to. Your function gets a 30% speed increase for minimal effort (the algorithms are already written for us, development time is minimal.) Also, it would seem you don't even need to extract from the original array. You could just read them all and insert them. That's another 30% speed increase. I just realized that.

Comment: But you can already rebuild the whole heap in O(n) so there's no reason to split it O(nlogn). Also, you can split binomial heap in O(logn) time and O(1) space

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ Rebuilding the heap in `O(n)` (Actually, it's `O(h)`) can only be done if you're removing a single element. As far as the space constraints, if you want a separate data structure, it's going to need it's own array.

Comment: @corsiKa Ok, but you can still do it in O(logn) time. Just like merging 2 binomial heaps can be done in O(logn) using binary long addition on the trees of the binomial heaps where each time you have a reminder you merge 2 trees,  splitting binomial heaps can be done the same but instead using a binary long subtraction where each time you need to borrow a digit you split a tree. Sorry for bad English

Comment: @corsiKa also you use pointers for binomial heaps not an array

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in k*log(n) by simply removing k elements from the original heap and moving them to a new different heap. (this assuming the heap is a minimum heap, if it's a maximum heap then it can be done the same way in (n-k)log(n))

Answer (score 0):

Because the binomial heap's trees can be represented as the binary digits of n, you can split the heap in O(log(n)) simply by doing a binary long subtraction between n and k where each time you need to "borrow" a digit what you split in half one tree. it's exactly like binomial trees merge but using a binary long subtraction instead of addition on the trees.